# Django: passing JSON from view to template

Tags: javascript, json, django, django-1.7, cal-heatmap

In `views.py`, I have time series data stored in a dictionary as follows:

```
time_series = {"timestamp1": occurrences, "timestamp2": occurrences}
```

where each `timestamp` is in unix time and `occurrences` is an integer.

Is there a way to pass the time series data as a json object in the context of the `render` function?

**Why do this:** I am using [Cal-heatmap](https://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/) on the front end which requires the data to be in json format. Ajax requests work just fine for now but I ideally would like to use the `render` approach if possible.

Comment: Update from 2021 with simple, built-in solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66658209/4671300

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If a frontend library needs a to parse JSON, you can use the `json` library to convert a python dict to a JSON valid string. Use the `escapejs` filter

```
import json

def foo(request):
    json_string = json.dumps(<time_series>)
    render(request, "foo.html", {'time_series_json_string': json_string})


<script>
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse('{{ time_series_json_string | escapejs }}');
</script>
```

Comment: How about `var jsonObject = {{ time_series_json_string }};`? If you know **for sure** your data cannot contain unicode escapes or the `</script` string.

Comment: @spectras indeed, good point in the context of this particular question. Just in case this post gets interpreted for a different payload I guess :P

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita this works great! is there any reason to pick this approach over an ajax request approach or vice versa, in general?

Comment: @JayKarimi only because this question specifically asked for the `render` approach. The reasons not to use ajax would be: apparently this is not necessarily dynamic content. Why add AJAX JS / callbacks, ajax view + template render, if not necessary. If anything AJAX should cause slower rendering *and* additional complexity for a 2 key object. Or maybe not: the page could be more easily full page cached while the AJAX is cached more frequently. All depends!

Comment: Is this method safe if your json has user submitted content?

Answer (score 8):

Pass a `json.dumps` value to the template. It is already a valid JSON string so you don't need to parse it or anything. Only when rendering it in the template, mark it as `safe` to prevent HTML quoting.

```
# views.py
def foo(request):
    time_series_json = json.dumps(time_series)
    return render(request, 
                  "template.html", 
                  context={'time_series': time_series_json})

# in the template
<script>
    const timeSeries = {{ time_series | safe }};
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't strictly true. A JSON string is meant to be rendered inside a string, not as a general JSON object like an array or map. For example, if you use your method to render a map, it's going to be corrupted since it'll render all keys and values with a backslash to escape it's quotes for use inside a string. This might work for arrays containing only numbers, since they won't need any escaping, but that's a niche case.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [Django templates built-in filter `json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script):

In `views.py`:

```
render(request, "foo.html", {'time_series_data': time_series})
```

In the template `foo.html`:

```
{{ time_series_data|json_script:"time-series-data" }}
```

In your script:

```
const timeSeriesData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('time-series-data').textContent);
```

Comment: I tried and after parsing the JSON, when I try to get the keys I get every character of the JSON as key, it doesn't recognize the JSON keys. What's going on?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74563785/passing-a-json-object-from-django-to-javascript-doesnt-work-properly/74563861#74563861

Answer (score 2):

have you tried passing something like `json.dumps(time_series)` to the render function?