# How to export a python-highcharts chart for use in flask or django?

Tags: python, json, highcharts

It's really all in the question but I'm using [python-highcharts](https://github.com/kyper-data/python-highcharts) to build something like [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m98r6kdx/) for inclusion in a Python Flask app. I can get it to work in the Jupyter notebook from where I can save it to an html file or export it as an iframe or div code block. But I can't get any of these to work in the flask html page. The inclusion block in the flask page looks like:

```
<p>
{% if result != None %}
<div id="my-chart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  {{result|safe}}
</script>
{% endif %}
</p>
```

and the relevant header parts:

```
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

I've managed to get it working with [pandas-highcharts](https://github.com/gtnx/pandas-highcharts) but in this way I can't send tooltip formatting javascript functions via the dict-to-json-to-browser path... so a solution to either issue would be great.

J.

Comment: Ok, so what doesn't work for you? What do you have in `result` and what is generated in HTML?

Comment: @PawełFus The issue is not with the highcharts library but rather with the python interfaces I'm using. 

If I use pandas-highcharts I can neatly send a <script> block to the html template but as this is a python dictionary converted to json, I cannot send javascript functions (for tooltip formatting).

If I use python-highcharts (in the IPython notebook) I can pass javascript functions (for tooltip formatting) but I can't export the chart code to json for inclusion via `{{ result|safe }}`.

In the end I built most of the javascript in the html template and passed only the data in a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First off:*

### **Writing JS functions in the HTML can (almost) always be prevented!**

One of the first principles you should stick to is to separate your static files. More on that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/).

You should only pass the variable into your script using `Jinja2/DjangoTemplatingLanguage` tags like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151229/django-passing-json-from-view-to-template), and write all your javascript functionality in your separate .js file, which is then imported along with other scripts, by your example:

```
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="{{ static_url }}/js/my-highstock-project.js"></script>
```

This way you have nice code separation and it is also (somewhat) more safe.

### Which leads us to the problem at hand; importing...

*So secondly:*
`HighCharts` needs `jQuery` to be implemented before it can work. That is probably your problem.

To import `jQuery` include this to your header:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```